# Añadir líneas horizontales en una función escalonada

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Adjunto gráfico, en el que quiero dibujar la línea y=0 para x<3 y la línea y=1 para x>=8, es decir el resultado sería la imagen con las dos líneas horizontales rojas.
Estas son las instrucciones que he utilizado y con las que no consigo las dos líneas rojas. Se trata de la función de distribución de una variable aleatoria discreta.

Gracias

```
df <- data.frame(x=Asignaturas, y=`solF`)
df$xend <- c(df$x[2:nrow(df)],NA)
df$yend <- df$y
p <- (ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=x), linetype=2,color="grey") +
geom_point() +  # Solid points to left
geom_point(aes(x=xend, y=y), shape=1) +  # Open points to right
geom_segment()# Horizontal line 
+geom_text(aes(label = paste0(solF,''),vjust = -0.5), color = "black")+ylab("Función de
distribucción")+ xlab("Asignaturas"))

p
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás en SO en ESPAÑOL, traduce tu pregunta o acabará cerrada. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y hagas el [tour] y de paso te ganes tus primeras medallas. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar las dos lineas de forma manual mediante el `geom_segment()`:

```
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 3, yend = 0), color="red") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 8, y = 1, xend = 9, yend = 1), color="red")
```